# Display shortcode in text field with wordpress settings api

Tags: shortcode, settings-api

I'm trying to figure out how to display the output of a shortcode in a text field using wordpress settings api. My goal is to create a few shortcodes so that I can use one or the other along with some other text. In the example I'm trying to display the product title then some text in the text field such as **sorry, [oosd-title] has sold out** to display **sorry, red short has sold out**.

The shortcode was easy enough to do

```
function oosdfw_title_display() {

return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode( 'oosd-title', 'oosdfw_title_display' );
```

And this generates the text field in the admin area. It's all working except the shortcode displays [oosd-title] instead of the product title

```
function oosdw_text_field_6_render(  ) { 

$options = get_option( 'oosdw_settings' );
?>
<input type="text" name="oosdw_settings[oosdw_text_field_6]" value="<? 
php echo $options["oosdw_text_field_6"]; ?>">
    <?php

}
```

I'm not quite sure what I have to do to get the shortcode to generate in the on the frontend. I did try esc_html but wasn't entirely sure how to use it or where to place it

Answer (score 0):

**Use a shortcode with parameters**

```
function oosdfw_title_display($atts) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'before' => 'Sorry, ',
        'after' => ' has sold out.',
    ), $atts );

    return $a['before'].get_the_title().$a['after'];
}

add_shortcode( 'oosd-title', 'oosdfw_title_display' );
```

**Put shortcode in text field** and modify `before` and `after` parameters to suit your requirements.

```
[oosd-title before="Sorry " after = " has sold out."]
```

There is no need to display the *output of shortcode* within text field

**Front-end**

```
$options = get_option( 'oosdw_settings' );
echo do_shortcode( $options["oosdw_text_field_6"]);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I can't quite get it to work. I followed your updated answer and the product title doesn't display but it displays with `text[oosd-title]` The shortcode does work if I use it in the text editor though

Comment: Remove all other text from text field and try!

Comment: Shortcodes works only if placed on separate line.

Comment: Yep, tried that already. Was the first thing I tried

Comment: I read your question again and this is what I understood:
You want `sorry, [oosd-title] has sold out.` in your text field to display `sorry, red short has sold out` on **front-end**. 
Am I right?

Comment: That's correct, but the sold out bit to be editable with the text field

Comment: @JohnCook I have updated the answer.